# IsVisibleChanged is not triggered when TabItem visibility is programatically updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a tab control with three tabs, two of which are have Visibility set to collapsed when the program starts, becomes visible under certain conditions, and can later become collapsed again. If the TabItem being collapsed is the currently selected Tab, it's content remains visible even though it has become collapsed.

The tabs' visibility is bound to my ViewModel, and is updated that way.

It will always be the case that I want the first tab to be activated when any of the tab's visibility changes. I've tried to make a simple code behind to handle this case, but the only time that code is hit is when my UserControl is loaded/unloads. The Handler is never invoked when the tab's visibility is updated. I tried setting the IsVisibleChanged property on both the tabcontrol and its items, but I can't get the codebeind to hit.

**Here's my xaml:**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        IsVisibleChanged="TabControl_IsVisibleChanged>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Platform.Presentation;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" IsVisibleChanged="TabControl_IsVisibleChanged">
    <TabItem Header="View 1" x:Name="_view1Tab" IsVisibleChanged="TabControl_IsVisibleChanged">
        <local:SingleWorkspaceView/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="View 2" x:Name="_view2Tab" Visibility="{Binding TabVisibility}" IsVisibleChanged="TabControl_IsVisibleChanged">
        <local:WorkspaceDeploymentView/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="View 3" x:Name="_view3Tab" Visibility="{Binding TabVisibility}" IsVisibleChanged="TabControl_IsVisibleChanged">
        <local:TabDeploymentView/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**Here's my code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace MyNameSpace
{                                               
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for TopLevelControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class TopLevelControl : UserControl
{
        ApplicationViewModel _viewModel;
        public TopLevelControl()
        {
            _viewModel = new ApplicationViewModel();
            base.DataContext = _viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TabControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           TabItem tab = sender as TabItem;
           if(tab != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
           {
              _tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Is there some reason the event is not firing?

Comment: Event handler hits for me whenever any tabItem's visibility changed. However in place of `(bool)e.NewValue` don't you think you need `!(bool)e.NewValue`?

Comment: Weird. I removed the resource dictionary and suddenly saw hits from the tab items as the view was loading, but subsequent visibility changes didn't cause the handler to get run.

Answer (score 2):

Lets do it in MVVM way without any codebehind

> xaml here we have binded SelectedIndex="{Binding TabSelectedIndex}" of TabControl

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding TabSelectedIndex}">
        <TabItem Header="abc">
            <Button Content="ok"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="xyz" Visibility="{Binding TabVisibility}">
            <Button Content="ok"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="pqr" Visibility="{Binding TabVisibility}">
            <Button Content="ok"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

> xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext =new  ViewModel();
    }
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int tabSelectedIndex;
    //this will be bound to the SelectedIndex of Tabcontrol
    public int TabSelectedIndex
    {
        get { return tabSelectedIndex; }
        set { tabSelectedIndex = value;
            Notify("TabSelectedIndex"); 
        }
    }

    Visibility tabVisibility;
    //this will be binded to the Visibility of TabItem 
    public Visibility  TabVisibility
    {
        get { return tabVisibility; }
        set
        {
            tabVisibility = value;
            //this is the logic that will set firstTab selected when Visibility will be collapsed
        if (tabVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            tabSelectedIndex = 0;
            Notify("TabSelectedIndex");
        }
            Notify("TabVisibility"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

I hope this will help. If it will help then say MVVM Rocks :)

Comment: I definitely appreciate your solution, but I wanted to avoid making a viewmodel for this for a bunch of reasons:

---A solution along the lines of what I'm trying _should_ work, and would be much fewer lines of code. I'm curious why the IsVisibleChanged property isn't being triggered.
---I don't mind having code-behinds when it's strictly dealing with the view, and not acting on anything that has to do with the model
---Related to the first point, making a view model to handle this is a lot of code just to deal with an edge case :(

Comment: I think you already have ViewModel from where you are binding Visibility

Comment: I do have a ViewModel for the Application as a whole, which keeps track of the application's state. But to solve this problem using MVVM, I'd have to create another view model for the TabItem class, as @ethicallogics did in his solution.

Comment: +1 I ended up doing this as a workaround. I just put the SelectedIndex property in my existing application view model. Still don't know why those events weren't firing though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void TabItem_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TabItem tabItem && tabItem.Parent is TabControl tabControl && tabItem.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed && tabControl.SelectedItem == tabItem)
    {
        tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items.Cast<TabItem>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```